# List of binary numbers: How many positions have a one and zero

Tags: python, numpy, numba, binary-operators

I have a list of integers, e.g. `i=[1,7,3,1,5]` which I first transform to a list of the respective binary representations of length `L`, e.g. `b=["001","111","011","001","101"]` with `L=3`.

Now I want to compute at how many of the `L` positions in the binary representation there is a `1` as well as a zero `0`. In my example the result would be `return=2` since there is always a `1` in the third (last) position for these entries. I would be happy for any comment. I think, ideally I should do many Xor operations at the same time. However, I'm not sure how I can do this efficiently.

Edit: Thanks for the many answers!! I have to check which one is the fastest.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be 3?

Comment: Note that I rolled back your question to the previous version, as you should not use an answer to turn it into a follow-up question. Good to see you posted that follow-up question now on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251998/109294)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One observation is that if you take the AND of all numbers, and also the OR of all numbers, then the XOR of those two results will have a 1 where the condition is fulfilled.

So:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_, or_

def count_mixed_bits(lst):
    xor = reduce(and_, lst) ^ reduce(or_, lst)
    return bin(xor).count("1")


count_mixed_bits([1,7,3,1,5])  # 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes a lot of sense to me and seems quite simple

Comment: I need this to work inside a numba function. Therefore I tried to modify your code. Maybe you have some expertise with numba as well? I'm not sure if my modification is optimal.

Comment: Please don't modify your question to add a follow-up question. If you have a follow-up question, consider posting a new question concentrating on that only. However, if your follow-up question is about size of the code and/or efficiency (while you have working code), then consider posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, I suspect it is not very efficient, but it is easy to understand.

I loop over the digits and find the unique set, then I count the number of entries with a set length of two:

```
# create a binary list of 3 elements from input list of integers
i=[1,7,3,1,5]
b=['{0:03b}'.format(x) for x in i]

# loop over the digit position (1,2,3)
cnt=[]
for pos in range(3):
    cnt.append(len(set([c[pos] for c in b])))

# cnt now contains a list of either 2(=both 1 and 0 present) or 1 (unique)
# so now we count the number of entries with "2"
result=cnt.count(2)
print (result)
```

answer:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is tagged with numpy but your array is not a numpy array.
Here is a solution that uses numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def has_zeroes_and_ones_at_index(arr, index_from_right):
    shifted_arr = np.right_shift(arr, index_from_right)
    has_one_at_index = shifted_arr % 2 == 1
    return(True in has_one_at_index and False in has_one_at_index)

arr = np.array([1, 7, 3, 1, 5])
res= has_zeroes_and_ones_at_index(arr, 1)
print(res)
```

Because the numbers are stored in binary we can use bit shifting to move all bits of the numbers to the right and then look at the last bit. We dont have to cast them to a binary format before.
5 (101) right shift by one -> 2 (010)

We then create a mask to see which numbers have a one in the last bit and return True when in the mask there is at least one True element and one false element.

Comment: nice use of bit shifting, I corrected the array to that of the question, because your addition 2 made the result always True.  Also, just to note that it doesn't exactly answer the question as one still needs to loop over the bit positions and count the number of Trues.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`numpy.binary_repr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html) method that accepts length. Unfortunately, it can't handle arrays. But you can apply a functionality of [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) instead:

```
def check(arr, lenght):
    positions = np.array(np.unravel_index(i, (2,)*lenght))
    return positions, np.sum(np.sum(positions, axis=1) != len(arr))

>>> positions, output = check(i, 3)
>>> print(positions)
>>> print(output)
[[0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python bitwise operators for this task.

```
def find(aList, nn):
    return sum( 
      filter( 
        lambda bb: bb > 0 ,
        (
          ( 1 <= (sum( (aa & 1<<kk) > 0 for aa in aList)) < len(aList) )
          for kk in range(nn)
        )
      )
    )
```

---

```
>>> find([1,7,3,1,5],3)
2
>>> find([],3)
0
>>> find([7],3)
0
>>> find([7,1],3)
2
>>> find([7,1,7],3)
2
```